# Show/hide items when comparing arrays

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Here is my problem:

1. I have an `tags` array used to loop to create a list of checkboxes.
2. I have a `selectTags` array to store selected tags. Everytime a tag is check/uncheck, this array is updated.
3. I have an `images` object that store image url and image tags, like this:

```js
days : {
    day1 : {
        image1: {
            url : '',
            tags: ['tag1', 'tag2']
        },
        image2: {
            url : '',
            tags: ['tag1']
        },
    },
    day2 : {
        image1: {
            url : '',
            tags: ['tag3']
        },
        image2: {
            url : '',
            tags: ['tag1']
        },
    }
}
```

Inside my loop component, I do the follow to show images:

```
<figure v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index">
    <img :src="image['url']" alt="">
</figure>
```

Now, I need to hide/show images based on what tags are selected

Comment: returns a method for v-if | v-show and within this method you make a filter, but pass the current image into that method Ex: method (image), inside you compare if the tag contains inside the selected tag. @marcelo2605

Comment: @HamiltonGabriel Thanks for the tip. I started adding `v-show="filterImage(image)"` to the `<figure>` and add a `console.log('a')` inside this method. The problem here is this method is not activated when I check/uncheck a tag.

Comment: @marcelo2605 you can emit an event from the `figure` component on check/uncheck then call the above `filterImage` function.

Comment: @Michael I think I need to emit an event from checkbox component to figure component, right? Checkbox component already emit an event to main component when a checkbox is check/uncheck. That because `selectTags` is registered on main component and sended for both components via props. How can I emit and event from parent to children and how can I send the `image` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution:

```
<figure
    v-for="(image, index) in images" 
   :key="index" 
    v-show="selectTags.filter(item => image['tags'].indexOf(item) > -1).length"
>
    <img :src="image['url']" alt="">
</figure>
```

I don't known if this is the best approach. So, suggestions are welcome.

Comment: As long as you didn't provide much info about your components and data - there is nothing we can say about this solution.